# Can I use the code I found in a question for my Drupal site?

Tags: support, answers

Can I use the code shown in the answer for [How can I add a CSS class to the body tag based on the current path alias?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223953/add-class-to-body-based-on-path-alias) in a Drupal site?

Comment: Probably yes, but have a lawyer check over https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286582/can-we-get-some-explicit-clarification-on-the-intended-legal-usage-of-code-fro and its linked posts if you want to be 100% sure in the context of your own product/jurisdiction

Comment: What about that post?https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange

Comment: Yep read that one too

Comment: lol, such a small code snipped. Drupal API code is fair use, they can't copyright that. If this was a module, that would be a diff story. If you're paranoid just change the variable names, but even here you're going too far! I am sure `$current_path` and `$path_alias` are common intuitive variable names